# Did the original EPR really consider an entangled state?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, epr-experiment

Or did only the subsequent thought experiments (Bohm & Aharonov, Bell) that introduced spin examine entangled states?

The wikipedia article titled 'EPR paradox' claims as much: 'The thought experiment involves a pair of particles prepared in an entangled state'.

However: Since they treat the wave function of the composite system as separable (for example equation 7 or 8 in the original paper), are we not by definition dealing with a non-entangled state?

I am referring to this paper: https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777

Comment: Do you expect people to find out what paper you mean by "original paper", and look up the equation themselves?

Comment: I added the link to the original EPR paper.
If I get to it, I can tex the two equations, but one would have to read or be familiar with the paper anyway to answer the question.

Comment: Please don't link to PDFs. -- Regarding your comment *"but one would have to read or be familiar with the paper anyway to answer the question"*, questions and answers here are meant to be useful for future readers.  And: How can you expect people to put more effort into their answer than you put into your question?

Comment: How are those equations separable? There is a sum in front!

Comment: The original EPR refers to a pair of correlated  particles. The whole point was to show locality, reality and common sense. The later concept of entangled particles/ spooky action at a distance was someone else’s interpretation of the experimental results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entangled state is a sum over basis states formed from the outer product of vectors in the one particle states. Using ket notation, the EPR paper considered states of the form
$$\int dp |p\rangle_\mathrm A|-p\rangle_\mathrm B$$
(where I have replaced P & Q used by EPR with A & B for Alice and Bob). Thus if Alice measures $q$ Bob must measure $-q$. This is an entangled state, and may be compared to the Bell state, in which the sum takes place over only spin 
$$  |\uparrow\rangle_\mathrm A|\downarrow\rangle_\mathrm B+ |\downarrow\rangle_\mathrm A|\uparrow\rangle_\mathrm B$$

Comment: thank you! My point of confusion was that the definition of a separable state allows for sums over one index in the state operator notation, but not sums of composite state kets